# What is wrong with /dev/stdin in an ubuntu docker container with -v used?

Tags: docker, stdin

I have the following Dockerfile on Mac OS X. Then I built a docker image.

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu
$ docker build -t ubtsrv1 .
$ docker image ls -a |grep ubtsrv1
ubtsrv1             latest              1d9c17228a9e        2 weeks ago         86.7MB
```

If I start a container like the following, `main.sh` runs correctly.

```
$ docker run -it --rm 1d9c17228a9e
root@868b92725d0a:/# cat > main.sh <<'EOF'
> #!/bin/bash
> # vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:
> 
> x=$(< /dev/stdin)
> echo "$x"
> EOF
root@868b92725d0a:/# chmod +x main.sh 
root@868b92725d0a:/# ./main.sh <<EOF
> a
> b
> EOF
a
b
```

If I start a container like the following, I got an error when I run `main.sh`. Does anybody know what is wrong? Thanks.

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v /tmp:/tmp 1d9c17228a9e
root@c5ee57db53e6:/# cd /tmp/
root@c5ee57db53e6:/tmp# ./main.sh <<EOF
> a
> b
> EOF
./main.sh: line 4: /dev/stdin: No such file or directory
root@c5ee57db53e6:/tmp# cat main.sh 
#!/bin/bash
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

x=$(< /dev/stdin)
echo "$x"
root@8f207db2cb92:/# cd
root@8f207db2cb92:~# cp /tmp/main.sh .
root@8f207db2cb92:~# ./main.sh <<EOF
> a
> b
> EOF
./main1.sh: line 4: /dev/stdin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Also the last thing you ran shows the error on `main1.sh` not `main.sh`. Not sure if that's a typo, but none of the examples you've shown were reproducible using `docker run --name ubtsrv1 -it --rm ubuntu:latest` or `docker run --name ubtsrv1 -it --rm -v /tmp:/tmp ubuntu:latest`